# Como adicionar destaque sintático de Dart ao VIM?

Tags: dart, vim

Estou iniciando os estudos de Flutter. Para isso, estou usando como editor o [vim](/questions/tagged/vim). Considero opção usar uma IDE, porém para coisas rápidas e menores, usar o `vim` é mandatório para o como estou estudando.

O `vim` que eu recebo não vem com o destaque sintático para Dart. Como faço para ativá-lo?

> Estou usando o `vim` no WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) e via Git Bash, se isso for relevante para a resposta

Comment: Com algum gerenciador de plugins, acredito que instalar o [dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin) seja bastante simples

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, na verdade já fiz no WSL isso seguindo o que está aí descrito (inclusive, instalei usando o `vim-plug` depois de meia horinha vendo as diferenças entre os gerenciadores). Estou aqui repesquisando para instalar no Git Bash e adicionar conhecimento à comunidade.

Comment: Sempre usei o vim-plug e nunca tive problema :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como mencionado pelo [@ACWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397390/como-adicionar-destaque-sint%c3%a1tico-de-dart-ao-vim?noredirect=1#comment780815_397390), o primeiro passo é instalar um gerenciador de plugins do [vim](/questions/tagged/vim).

Por uma questão de simplicidade, pareceu-me mais fácil usar o [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).

Segundo o guia do `vim-plug`, a primeira coisa a se fazer é deixá-lo auto-carregável pelo próprio `vim`. A priori, basta colocar o script `.vim` no diretório `~/.vim/autoload` para fazer isso. O arquivo para isso já está pronto para isso: basta baixar o `plug.vim` do repositório. O único *branch* com desenvolvimento ativo no momento é o `master`, sendo os demais deveras antigo. Então, precisamos acessar, do usuário do GitHub `junegunn`, o respositório `vim-plug`, no branch `master`, e baixar o arquivo `plug.vim` dentro do diretório `~/.vim/autoload`. O GitHub disponibiliza acesso aos arquivos estáticos dentro do domínio `raw.githubusercontent.com`, na seguinte formação da URL:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
\_______________________________/ \_____/  \______/ \____/ \______/ 
               |                     |          |     |        |
               |                     v          |     v        v
               |            Usuário do GitHub   v   Branch    Path
               v                           Repositório
     Domínio de arquivos estáticos
```

No `README`, o autor do gerenciador de plugins fala para fazer o download através do seguinte comando:

```bsh
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Mas, o que isso significa?

- `curl`: comando usado para se conectar em alguma URL
- `-f`: falha silenciosamente
- `-L`: seguir os links de redirecionamento (http status 3xx)
- `-o <file>`: direciona o conteúdo baixado para o arquivo `<file>`
- `--create-dirs`: garante a existência dos diretórios necessários (como se fosse um `mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload`) para salvar o `output`

Após fazer isso, basta colocar no arquivo de configuração (normalemnte o `~/.vimrc`) um bloco de `vim-plug`. O bloco inicia com `call plug#begin()` e termina com `call plug#end()`.

Dentro desse bloco, você pode especificar os plugins que deseja usando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
call plug#begin()

" comentário vem precedidos de aspas

Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'
" |           |
"Comando   Usuário/repositório no github

Plug 'https://github.com/junegunn/vim-github-dashboard.git'
"        |
"      Também aceita qualquer repositório git com a URL completa,
"      o github é inferido na inexistência

call plug#end()
```

> Tem mais algumas nuances para o `vim-plug`, mas o principal para o fim de adicionar o destaque sintático é isso

O plugin que eu desejo é o [`dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin`](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin). Então, só colocá-lo no `~/.vimrc`:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin

call plug#end()
```

Quando iniciar mais uma vez o `vim`, é necessário pedir para o `vim-plug` instalar o necessário, através do comando `PlugInstall`. E *voi-là*:

[image: destaque sintático de dart no vim]

> Os mesmos passos funcionaram para o Git Bash e para o Ubuntu via WSL